# Create a timer that runs each second, on the second?

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer

I have a countdown timer to a specific date. It looks pretty good, and updates each second to show the countdown. Here is the code I'm using to create the timer:

```
func scheduleTimeLabelsUpdateTimer() {

    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
    components.second! += 1

    let nextSecondDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!

    let timer = Timer(fireAt: nextSecondDate, interval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimeLabels), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)

}
```

However, I'd like it to update each second, *on the second,* so that the clock updates at the same time as each second passes by. Right now it updates each second from when this method is called, which is in `viewDidLoad()`.

For example if the countdown is set for midnight, I want it to hit zero exactly at midnight. Right now it may hit zero slightly after midnight, depending on how far into the second it was when the user opened this screen.

EDIT: This is how the countdown is displayed to the user. `updateTimeLabels()` just sets the text for each of those labels based on the amount of time left until that date. I would like each of the labels to be updated exactly on each second. This way the countdown will "hit zero" exactly on time. Notice how right now, the number of seconds hits zero, and then the system clock on the status bar updates. I would like these to happen at the same time.

[image]

This code, which I found somewhere on Stack Overflow many months ago, is being called in `updateTimeLabels()` to calculate the remaining time:

```
public func timeOffset(from date: Date) -> (days: Int, hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
    // Number of seconds between times
    var delta = Double(self.seconds(from: date))

    // Calculate and subtract whole days
    let days = floor(delta / 86400)
    delta -= days * 86400

    // Caluclate and subtract whole hours
    let hours = floor(delta / 3600).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 24)
    delta -= hours * 3600

    // Calculate and subtract whole minutes
    let minutes = floor(delta / 60.0).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)
    delta -= minutes * 60

    // What's left is seconds
    let seconds = delta.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)

    return (Int(days), Int(hours), Int(minutes), Int(seconds))
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by hit zero?

Comment: The countdown timer shows the days, hours, minutes, and seconds until a certain date. If the date is set to midnight tonight, then I want all those labels to say "0" exactly when it becomes midnight tonight, not a part of a second later.

Comment: how it behaves right now?

Comment: Right now, the timer starts exactly one second after the user opens the screen. So if it is half a second into the current second, the labels will always update at half a second into each second. So the user would not see the timer hit all zeroes until half a second past midnight.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `Timer` is scheduled on the run loop and other things are happening in the run loop, it isn't particularly accurate; it will fire *after* the specified interval has passed, but not necessarily *exactly* when the interval has passed.

Rather than trying to schedule the timer for the desired time, you should run your timer faster than 1 second, say at 0.5 seconds and update your time remaining label each time the timer fires.  This will give a smoother update to the display:

```
var timer: Timer? 

func scheduleTimeLabelsUpdateTimer() {

self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        self.updateTimeLabels()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Don't do all of that math; iOS has nice libraries built in to do all of this for you; Simply create your target date and use `DateComponents` to work it out for you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    var targetTime: Date!
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var components = DateComponents()

        components.setValue(3, for: .month)
        components.setValue(3, for: .day)
        components.setValue(2017, for: .year)
        components.setValue(0, for: .hour)
        components.setValue(0, for: .minute)
        components.setValue(1, for: .second)


        self.targetTime = calendar.date(from: components)


        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in

            self.updateLabel()

        })

        self.dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long
        self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func updateLabel() {
        let now = Date()
        self.label.text = self.dateFormatter.string(from: now)


        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: now, to: self.targetTime)

        self.countDownLabel.text = String(format: "%d days %d hours, %d minutes %d seconds", components.day!, components.hour!, components.minute!,components.second!)

    }


}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work... It's still behaving the same as before.

Comment: Can you show more code?  How are you tracking time remaining?  How are you updating the labels?  What precisely are you seeing?

Comment: I added more details to the original post. To update the labels I'm calculating the remaining time and then just setting the text on each label.

Comment: Here is some code I created that sets a countdown timer for "now + 2 minutes + whatever seconds  are needed to make it end at :00" - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/3ce44b6f7e2a29db3ba28d1ce3314e7e

Comment: Okay, I switched to using the built-in library. But it still isn't updating right on time. It still updates on each second after the user opens the screen, not on each second according to the actual system clock. So it's off if the user doesn't open the screen at exactly 0 seconds for the current date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137028/discussion-between-paulw11-and-compc).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you never use nanosecond when you init your component

So the timer will always hit at the round second number.

I test your code below print the `Date()` in the selector [image]

I'm not sure if this is what you are talking about  "hit zero", hope this would help